# Euclidean Geometry workbook help

Tags: euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I was introduced to Euclidean geometry through a workbook for middle/high schoolers that introduced a beginning proof and through its solution, introduced another (more advanced) proof. I’m having an incredible time trying to find that book and/or something comparable. Does anyone here have something along this vein they could recommend?

Eternally grateful!

Comment: [This book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0961-4) by a first-rate mathematician and teacher might be of interest.

Comment: [Honsberger's *Episodes*](https://www.amazon.com/Episodes-Nineteenth-Twentieth-Euclidean-Mathematical/dp/0883856395) is one of my favorites.

Answer (score 2):

Try [EGMO](https://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html) and [UKMT](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/product/87) books, as I have used them and like them a lot. Also, try the [106](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0979926947),[107](https://www.awesomemath.org/product/107-geometry-problems-from-amy/) and [110](https://www.amazon.sg/Geometry-Problems-International-Mathematical-Olympiad/dp/0988562227) series from Titu for alternatives (with increasing difficulty, all has a solution manual). If you want one with less Olympiad Mathematics flavor, try [Coexter](https://www.amazon.sg/Geometry-Revisited-H-S-Coxeter/dp/0883856190). Free sources include [this](https://www.olympiadgeometry.com/the-book.html) and [this](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/blog.nus.edu.sg/dist/2/12659/files/2021/08/Notes_MA2219-1.pdf) (the latter is a university course note).